# ASP.NET: object declared in _Default and instantiated in Page_Load() is null on second load

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a class that populates variables based on user information (checks AD, loads e-mail, distinguishedName, description field, etc etc). I declare the 'currentinfo' variable in the _Default Page, so I could hopefully have the object throughout the session.

I instantiate the class in the Page_Load event, but inside an If(!IsPostBack) so the constructor method runs only the first time. It works fine (the constructor populates my object and all the data is inside it as confirmed in debug mode with breakpoints). But when it leaves the If clause, the object becomes null again.

I wanted to have the object ready when the page loads so I could use it in other events, like button clicks. So, my questions are:

1 - I use the if(!IsPostBack) clause because my constructor takes some time to finish and everytime I click on a button it loads the page again and the object is instantiated if it´s not inside the if clause, so, how do I stop ASP.NET from reloading the page at every new event?

2 - If 1 is not possible how do I keep my object valid after it leaves the clause?
EDIT: 2 - How do I keep the variable state after the page loads for a second time?

```
public partial class ListUsers: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CurrentUserStructure currentuserinfo;
        List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> lsUsers;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                currentuserinfo = new CurrentUserStructure();
                lsUsers = currentuserinfo.GetUserList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use a Server side control, a `Postback` would always occur. So, you cannot stop ASP.NET from reloading the page at every new event. However, you can use the `IsPostback` Property to ensure that the variables are loaded the first time the page loads and on subsequent request the initialization code does not execute.
2. To Keep the variable state, you may either store the variable in a `Session` or in Page `ViewState`.

In the following code, I have added the property `ListOfUsers` and stored in session. The value is set first time at page load and subsequently the value can be read from Property.

```
    public partial class ListUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    // the object is declared here.
    // I understand it should be valid even if the page loads again
    CurrentUserStructure currentuserinfo = new CurrentUserStructure();

    private List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> ListOfUsers
    {
       get { 
              return Session["CurrentNamespace.ListOfUsers"] ?? new List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass>();
           }
       set {
                Session["CurrentNamespace.ListOfUsers"] = value;
           }
    }



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // everything from here on should happen only
        // the first time the page is loaded
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // bellow the lsUser object is constructed
            this.ListOfUsers = currentuserinfo.GetUserList();
        }   // up to here the lsUsers object is available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need viewstate to save the List

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            List<User> listUser = new List<User>();
            listUser.Add(new User() { Name = "U1" });
            listUser.Add(new User() { Name = "U2" });
            listUser.Add(new User() { Name = "U3" });

            ViewState["listUser"] = listUser;
        }
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = ViewState["listUser"]; //you can get the List from the ViewState
    }
```

and you need Serializable your class

```
 /// <summary>
/// you need Serializable the class so that you can save it in  ViewState 
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store session data in the `Session` item collection (see [How to: Save Values in Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx)). Create an instance of your `CurrentUserStructure` class in the [Session_Start event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx) in the Global.asax file, rather than in the page:

```
private void Session_OnStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext sessionContext = HttpContext.Current;

    // Create a new instance and store it for future use
    CurrentUserStructure newInstance = new CurrentUserStructure();
    sessionContext.Session["currentuserinfo"] = newInstance;
}
```

Then, in your `ListUsers` page, add a property that will read the value from the session-store.

```
public partial class ListUsers : System.Web.UI.Page{
    private CurrentUserStructure UserInfo
    {
        get
        {
            // Read the object from session store
            return (CurrentUserStructure) HttpContext.Current.Session["currentuserinfo"];
        }
    }
}
```

As to your second question, if you need `lsUsers` to be available outside of the `if` clause, then you need to declare it above the clause. For example:

```
List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> lsUsers = null;
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    lsUsers = currentuserinfo.GetUserList();
}
```

But the above probably won't be as relevant, once you implement your logic correctly. If you want to store the output of `GetUserList()` between requests, you have a couple of options:

1. If the output is required by multiple pages, it's probably best to store it in the session-store. You can do this also in the `Session_OnStart` event.
2. If the output is only required by this page, you can store the output in the page's `ViewState` (see [How to: Save Values in View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

In the alternative to option 1. above, it may make sense to store the value of `GetUserList()` in a public property inside the `CurrentUserStructure` class instance. For example:

```
public class CurrentUserStructure{
    private List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> users;
    public List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> Users{
        get {
                if(users==null){
                    users = GetUserList();
                }
                return users;
            }
    }

    // Note that this method is now private
    private List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> GetUserList() {
        // Implement your logic here
    }
}
```

This way, you'll be able to access the list from the CurrentUserStructure, which will be stored in the session-store:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // No need to check if this request is a post-back, because the value is stored elsewhere and does not need to be re-queried every time
        List<CurrentUserStructure.ListUserClass> lst = this.UserInfo.Users;

        // Do stuff with lst ...
    }
```